# Mock the return value (which is an object) created inside a test method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have referred the answers to [Mocking Objects Created Inside method Under test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069564/mocking-objects-created-inside-method-under-test), [How to mock objects created inside method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320127/how-to-mock-objects-created-inside-method/26323140) and other questions on net, but unable to understand why my solution is not working.
My method to test is:

```
private AmazonS3 s3client;    
public int getBucketFileCount(String bucketNameForJsons) {
    if (s3client.doesBucketExistV2(bucketNameForJsons)) {
        log.info("Bucket name is not available.");
        return 0;
    }
    ObjectListing listing = s3client.listObjects(bucketNameForJsons);
    List<S3ObjectSummary> objectListing = listing.getObjectSummaries();
    log.info("Counting s3client files");
    return objectListing.size();
}
```

The test case I have written is:

```
@Mock
private AmazonS3 s3clientMock;
@Mock
private ObjectListing listingMock;
private final String SAMPLE_BUCKET = "SAMPLE_BUCKET";

@InjectMocks
private Accessor accessor;

@Test
public void testGetBucketFileCount() {
    s3clientMock = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);
    listingMock = Mockito.mock(ObjectListing.class);
    //PowerMockito.when(s3clientMock.listObjects(anyString())).thenReturn(listingMock);
 //PowerMockito.doReturn(listingMock).when(s3clientMock).listObjects(anyString());
    //PowerMockito.when(s3clientMock.listObjects(Matchers.any(String.class))).thenReturn(listingMock);
    List<S3ObjectSummary> objectListing = new ArrayList<>();
    S3ObjectSummary objectSummary1 = Mockito.mock(S3ObjectSummary.class);
    S3ObjectSummary objectSummary2 = Mockito.mock(S3ObjectSummary.class);
    objectListing.add(objectSummary1);
    objectListing.add(objectSummary2);
    Mockito.doReturn(objectListing).when(listingMock).getObjectSummaries();
    int actualSize = accessor.getBucketFileCount(SAMPLE_BUCKET);
    //Assert.assertNotEquals(actualSize, EXPECTED_SIZE);
}
```

I have tried mocking `ObjectListing listing = s3client.listObjects(bucketNameForJsons);` in the following ways:

- `PowerMockito.when(s3clientMock.listObjects(anyString())).thenReturn(listingMock);`
- `PowerMockito.doReturn(listingMock).when(s3clientMock).listObjects(anyString());`
- `PowerMockito.when(s3clientMock.listObjects(Matchers.any(String.class))).thenReturn(listingMock);`

However, the value I get for `ObjectListing listing = s3client.listObjects(bucketNameForJsons)` is still null.

How do I make it take listingMock value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are overcomplicating things, asy you are already using the annotation:

```
@Mock
private AmazonS3 s3clientMock;
```

You should **stick** to that then. Meaning: either use [@RunWith or Mockito.initMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806345/runwithmockitojunitrunner-class-vs-mockitoannotations-initmocksthis). But you absolutely should **not** do `s3clientMock = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3.class);` **again**. (it doesn't hurt directly, but can lead to strange effects when you do it here, but do it different in another method)

Then: you don't need to use PowerMock(ito) here at all. You have two mocks, and you want to control and method call on each.

So a simple:

```
when(s3clientMock.listObjects(any())).thenReturn(listingMock);
when(listingMock.getObjectSummaries()).thenReturn(someList);
```

should do. `someList` would be a `List<S3ObjectSummary>`.

And then you could go:

```
assertThat(accessor.getBucketFileCount(SAMPLE_BUCKET), is(someList.size())
```

for example.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. So using plain Mockito ("       Mockito.when(s3clientMock.listObjects(anyString())).thenReturn(listingMock);") worked, but with PowerMockito it does not, right?

Comment: No. I am saying: plain Mockito works. You should **only only only** use PowerMock(ito) if you absolutely have to. Meaning: you only need PowerMock(ito) for mocking new/static calls. And that is something that can be avoided by writing **easy** to test code. When you write your own code, and you think "I need PowerMockito for that", then you are doing something **wrong**. In other words: the default should be to only depend on the (latest) version of Mockito, and use nothing but that ;-) ... makes sense?